# LDAP Signing with LDAP3 module in python

Tags: python-3.x, ldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I am using LDAP3 module to query information from Active Directory. To get information like GMSA password blob(ManagedPassword attribute), Active Directory expects that either connection is secure(LDAPS) or **LDAP signing(Integrity)** is used. I ran into a case where the environment doesn't have LDAPS cert installed, and possibility of installing is ruled out. So the only option I am left with is using the LDAP signing. Anyone has an idea how to use LDAP signing while connecting to Active Directory over 389 either with LDAP3 module or some other?

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides to TLS (the S in LDAPS):

1. The server trusts the client
2. The client trusts the server

This has nothing to do with LDAP, but with TLS, the same TLS you use with https. So I'll use https for my lecture before I actually answer your question.

### 1. Server trusts the client

Most of the time, the server is unable to trust the client. Imagine if you had to establish a trust relationship every time you visited a new https web page! So the server is hardly ever configure to trust its clients. Even if your LDAP server is in a better position to trust its clients (for example, it could hold their certificates), it is usually not configured like that. When it is, we call it mutual TLS or two-way TLS.

The trust will come by authentiating with a password or a Kerberos ticket over a secure connection, after a single-sided TLS connection is established. So nothing to worry about here.

### 2. Client trusts the server

Some servers have misconfigured TLS. Here is a [test server that uses a certificate that your browser (or operating system) does not trust](https://untrusted-root.badssl.com/).

But if you click on "Advanced" and proceed to visit the website (in Chrome, ymmv), the content (a large red page) is shown to you because **you** decided to "trust" the website anyway by ignoring/accepting the untrusted certificate this one time.

Of course, if you cannot trust the server with certificates, there is a possibility you are sending your credentials to a rogue server. That is probably unlikely so I'll let deal with that possibility and answer your question.

### Connecting to LDAPS without any certificates

Just instruct your LDAPS library to skip the certificate validation and continue, just like you did manually on that test page.

For [python-ldap](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/reference/ldap.html?highlight=OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT#ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT), add this right before you call `ldap.initialize`:

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
ldap.initialize("ldaps://ad.example.com")
```

or [ldap3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ssltls.html?highlight=certificate#the-tls-object) before you create the server:

```
import ssl
tls_configuration = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
server = Server("ldaps://ad.example.com", use_ssl=True, tls=tls_configuration)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this solution and get back. I am curious to see if Active Directory returns Group Managed Service Account information when I do this.

Comment: Active Directory has no way to tell if you have a valid certificate configuration or if you just ignored it.